# Debug node js with Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, visual-studio-code

I try to debug a Project in node JS with Visual Studio Code but i don't achieve.
I have built a simple project with the next commands:

> express myExpressApp
>  cd myExpressApp 
>  npm install
>  npm
>   start

My file launch.json:

[image]

I select the Option “Launch app.js” in Window “Debug”. The application run without problems. I put a breakpoint:

[image]

I give in Chrome the address: http://localhost:3000/

Visual Studio Code says: “Pause on breakpoint”, but I don't see anything, I can press Continue and the application continues...

[image: Pause on breakpoint]

Edited: I use OS X 10.10 (I tested it and it works perfectly in Ubuntu.)

Comment: here is demo how to configure nodjs express debugging in VSC http://wiki.workassis.com/nodejs-express-debugging-using-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode 0.8.0 has problems with node versions older than 0.12.0. Upgrade to at least 0.12.0 or wait for the upcoming VSCode 0.9.0.

Comment: I had the node version 4.0.0 i have upgrade to 4.1.1 and it works perfectly =)

Answer (score 1):

When debugging with Visual Studio Code, there are many things you can do when you hit a breakpoint.

In order to go to the "debugging" view, you can either click the "bug" icon on the left or hit `Ctrl + Shift + D`.

You see `Paused on breakpoint.` in the **Call Stack** window.  That window includes the callstack and you can double-click the different frames to navigate through the corresponding source.

You can also see the **Variables** window here to see the values of the variables (local/global/closure/etc.).

One of the more used functionality parts of debugging in VS Code is the debug console.  In the debugging view, there's a little icon right next to the configuration that you're using that looks like the CLI character.  You can either click that or just do a command palette search (`Ctrl + Shift + P`) for `Debug: open Console`.  This will bring up the debugging console for your ad hoc debugging commands.

[The documentation on VS Code debugging is quite robust, too, so I recommend you take a look at this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the documentation VS Code debugging, but I do not work for me. The breakpoint is not displayed in yellow, and everything appears empty. It is very rare that I'm the only one who has this problem ...

[Screenshoot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb8iC.jpg).

Comment: @jcabello Hmm.. that does appear to be inconsistent.  What version of VS Code are you running at the moment?  Try updating to the most recent version that was just released.

Comment: @tr_stringer  I have the VS Code version 0.8.0. Is the latest version available.
I use OS X Yosemite 10.10 thanks!